# Text comparison in Dynamics Nav "C/AL"

Tags: dynamics-nav, text-manipulation

I would like to know if a text ends in '0000' in C/AL code, but I am not sure if I am doing something wrong or the documetned functions simply are not prensent in the version of NAV I am using (NAV 2016). [String Functions in NAV](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/developer/datatypes/devenv-text-data-type)
In any case I would like to know how can I do this if it's not with this functions.

```
Text.ENDSWITH('0000'); // Does not compile, 
//no autocomplete for the ENDSWITH function either
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Article you are referring to is about AL - the language for developing extensions for Nav 2018 and Dynamics 365.

Here is the link you’re looking for https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics-nav/text-data-type

No `ENDSWITH` analog though. You can use `COPYSTR` or `DELSTR` to simulate it.

Alternatively you can use .Net variable of type System.String to get access to all string functions of C#. C/AL’s text is assignable to .Net’s string.

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like this:

```
IF COPYSTR(TheText,STRLEN(TheText)-4) = '0000' THEN
```

Comment: Note that this will result in a run-time error if TheText is shorter than 5 characters. You should probably test for that situation first.